# C# Json.NET hide objects (not properties) when serializing

Tags: c#, object, serialization, json.net, resolver

I want to hide objects (not properties) when serializing with Json.Net.

The situation is:

In a list of images, there are many images, including attributes such as **Class**, **Name**, and **Layers**. Within the same **layer**, there are many shape objects, including attributes such as **DrawMode** and **Shape**, and each shape object may be a circle, rectangle, or polygon, with coordinate information.

The whole json is:

```
"Objects": [
    {
      "Class": "A",
      "Name": "image1",
      "Layers": [
        {
          "DrawMode": 0,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Circle",
            "Center": "667.126739375705,127.059044753667",
            "Radius": 0.0,
            "RadiusX": 86.377240728513485,
            "RadiusY": 86.377240728513485
          }
        },
        {
          "DrawMode": 0,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Polygon",
            "Point0": "1243.0011282437,308.048138397894",
            "Points": [
              "976.453553967657,452.839413313276",
              "1479.93230537796,847.724708537044",
              "1664.21210981572,535.107183151561"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "DrawMode": 1,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Rectangle",
            "P0": "565.114704776231,725.968409176382",
            "P1": "960,1068.20233170365"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Class": "A",
      "Name": "image2",
      "Layers": [
        {
          "DrawMode": 0,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Circle",
            "Center": "226.171493042497,502.200075216247",
            "Radius": 0.0,
            "RadiusX": 146.94414717221008,
            "RadiusY": 146.94414717221008
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

When serializing, I want to hide all objects with the type "Circle".

If there are multiple shape objects in the Layers, including Circle and Polygon, only the shape object of type Circle will be hidden. However, if there are only shape objects of type Circle in the Layers, then the entire image object will be hidden.

So I want json is:

```
"Objects": [
    {
      "Class": "A",
      "Name": "image1",
      "Layers": [
        {
          "DrawMode": 0,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Polygon",
            "Point0": "1243.0011282437,308.048138397894",
            "Points": [
              "976.453553967657,452.839413313276",
              "1479.93230537796,847.724708537044",
              "1664.21210981572,535.107183151561"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "DrawMode": 1,
          "Shape": {
            "$type": "Rectangle",
            "P0": "565.114704776231,725.968409176382",
            "P1": "960,1068.20233170365"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Can anyone have any idea about this problem?

Thanks!

**Update Class:**

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public partial class AnnotationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AnnotationViewModel()
    {
    }

    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => Set(ref _id, value);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AnnotationObjectViewModel> _objects = new ObservableCollection<AnnotationObjectViewModel>();
    [JsonProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<AnnotationObjectViewModel> Objects
    {
        get => _objects;
        set => Set(ref _objects, value);
    }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class AnnotationObjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AnnotationObjectViewModel()
    {
    }

    private int _fontsize = 20;
    public int Fontsize
    {
        get => _fontsize;
        set => Set(ref _fontsize, value);
    }

    private string _class;
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Class
    {
        get => _class;
        set => Set(ref _class, value);
    }

    private string _name;
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => Set(ref _name, value);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<LayerViewModel> _layers = new ObservableCollection<LayerViewModel>();
    [JsonProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<LayerViewModel> Layers
    {
        get => _layers;
        set => Set(ref _layers, value);
    }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LayerViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private int _drawMode;
    [JsonProperty]
    public int DrawMode 
    {
        get => _drawMode;
        set => Set(ref _drawMode, value);
    }

    MShape _shape;
    [JsonProperty]
    public MShape Shape
    {
        get => _shape;
        set => Set(ref _shape, value);
    }
}
```

By the way, I know DefaultContractResolver, but I an not sure whether it can hide object

Comment: You need to post the classes you use to create data before serializaton or even the whole serialization code you have tried so far

Comment: What you have  posted not the most important classes and I still don't see your code to create an object for a serialization

Comment: @Serge I have updated all class, thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
var objects = MyClass.Objects;

var json = SerializeObjects(objects);

public string SerializeObjects(List<Object> objects)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        var obj = objects[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < obj.Layers.Count; j++)
        {
            if (obj.Layers[j].Shape.Type == "Circle") obj.Layers.RemoveAt(j);
        }
        if (obj.Layers.Count() == 0) objects.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);
}
```

Unfortunately you don't want to  post your classes, so objects will be taken from a your class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
 public List<Object> Objects { get; set;}
}
```

P.S. Removing after creating is probably not the best idea, but you have to post your code  in order we could offer the better solution

Comment: Thanks, Do you mean the Shape is circle will be removed from the List before serialization?

Comment: Have any idea about using DefaultContractResolver to hide objects?

Comment: @RickyChen I am sorry but I don't know what is a DefaultContractResolver

Comment: @RickyChen  And I recommend you to forget this word too, since it can not be used in this case

Comment: OK, I have updated all classes, but now my list is ObservableCollection, so is it need to be cloned when copied ObservableCollection right?